# Three.js colors rgb not correct

Tags: three.js

Working on a project in Three.js, and the RGB values I get back don't seem to correlate with the on screen graphics as they should.

I set a material like this:

```
var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors });
```

Apply it to a plane geometry, and then later change it with this:

```
face.color.setHSL(0, 0, 0.0)
```

Then repeatedly later change it with

```
face.color.offsetHSL(0, 0, 0.1)
```

The colors do in fact go from black to green, but then will not continue on and tend towards white.
Looking at the RBG values, they then tell me that the color values are equal to:

```
Color {b: 1, g: 1, r: 1}
```

and using getHSL it says:

```
{h: 0, s: 0, l: 1}
```

Yet the plane is very clearly green, and not white. 
I'm obviously missing something big about how colors work here, but I cant for the life of me make heads or tails of this. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks inadvance.

Comment: do you have any vertex colors?

Comment: can you demonstrate with a fiddle?

Comment: I don't have any vertex colors, and fiddle is giving me a hard time.

Comment: Oh i didn't even notice. So you make a green material, and then try to combine that with a black/white face color (vertex colors). What exactly do you expect? These two get multiplied. If you multiply black with green you get black. If you multiply white with green you get green. If you multiply red with green you get black etc. What do you expect to get?

Comment: A fiddle would help people like us have a better understanding of what you are trying to do, and what's going on. Right now this reads as `Hi, i just ate an Apple, but it didn't taste like a Banana, why?`

Comment: I expect the color to go from black to green to white as I add more lightness from 0. Instead it just goes from black to green, then maxes out. As for fiddle, when I run similar code it can't find any of the HSL functions, so I cant repeat it just yet. 
I just want to have a face that is of a green material, that I can completely control the face brightness of. Instead I can only control the darkness of it. How do I need to set this up differently?

Comment: Someone made a fiddle to help and I've edited it to show my problem:
What happens when you edit the material:
https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/5957/

What happens when you edit the face (like I'm trying to do):
https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/5973/

Comment: This thread was helpful to me: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14110